# Log-in screen shows up on secondary monitor

Tags: display

When I start my PC, the elementary login screen shows up on my secondary monitor, but when I sign in and get to the desktop, everything display-wise is correctly set up (dock and menu bar on primary monitor). How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this by setting the correct primary monitor via LightDM.

LightDM is elementaryOS's lock screen (aka pantheon-greeter)

1. First you need to find the name for your primary monitor using the command `xrandr`. It will be something similar to "HDMI1" or "DVI-0".
2. Once you have the correct monitor name you will need to edit the file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`. In that file you will need to add the following line:
3. `display-setup-script=xrandr --output HDMI-0 --primary`
4. Make sure the HDMI-0 in the line above is your own monitor name.
5. Restart computer

Answer (score 1):

It is an old bug. It has been reported here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1355561

I didn't find a workaround for this yet.

There is also a bounty open for this issue, here:
https://www.bountysource.com/issues/3733137-login-screen-is-the-resolution-of-the-primary-monitor-on-all-monitors